# Change the owner of a subdirectory on a mounted drive

Tags: mount, fstab, chown, ownership, dynamic-linking

I have my home folder linked to a folder on a mounted partition
in have mounted it via fstab and the uid is the id of root the gid too.

How do i change the owner of the subdirectorys on the mounted drive?
sudo chown -c user:root user/ does state to change the owner , but does not actually change it

Answer (score 2):

You can not change ownership on a read only filesystem. The `mount` command will list if the partition is mounted read only. Probably not the problem since you say it does not complain (as it would if it was read-only).

But you can also NOT change ownership on a filesystem that is NOT posix (that includes all Windows filesystems). Changing ownership on Windows filesystems is done when mounting the partition. 
If this is the case add "uid=1000,gid=1000" to the line in /etc/fstab related to this mount. 1000 is the main user; if you want another check the userid with `id -u {user}` and the groupid with `id -g {user}`.